# why capybara can't submit directly to put action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I was watching Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial, In chapter 9.2.2, Hartl says that we can't use capybara to issue put/patch requests directly to a model,

This was the test code:

```
describe "for wrong users" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
  before { valid_signin user}

  describe "when submitting a PATCH request to users#update" do
    before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to root_path}
  end
end
```

and valid_signin is like this, intially:

```
def valid_signin(user, options = {})
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email", with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in" 
end
```

These tests don't work, as when we issue a put request, we can't use capybara to do this.

So is it like this, that we can't use capybara to test any put/patch requests? And what we should do in general when we need to test put/patch requests and we can't use capybara?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara is for Behaviour Driver Development. Who's behaviour? Human beings.

Can a human being `patch`? Can he `put`? He can't. Only computers can.

Can a human being `visit`, `fill_in`, `click_button`? Yes he can. This is what Capybara for.

Bottom line, put computers' actions into unit testing and controller testing, mimic human beings in integration testing by Capybara.

Comment: Yes, I was confused because in railstutorial, this is done inside an integration test.

Comment: Hi i read your answer just now, but can't understand relation between capybara and valid_signin in this case! why valid_signin don't work ? it's invoked before he do "patch" ?

Comment: @medBo, the problem is not `valid_signin` but `patch user_path(wrong_user)`. You can't use PATCH, GET, POST etc in capybara.

Comment: if you see a rails tutorial as he says, you find that michael hart'l add an option to "valid_signin" (note : the name of this method in tutorial is "sign_in" instead of "valid_signin", so it's not important). the option added is if options[:no_capybara] then create a cookie ... you can see this here : http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users?version=4.0#top at listing 9.6

Comment: the problem here is that user can't sign in with the method "valid_signin" when we use patch/put later ! but what is the relation between them

Comment: @medBo, change `let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }` to `@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)` and refer to `@user` later on. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18578762/1721198

Comment: it says email already taken... but this is not the problem, are you looking for the link in my comment above ? in the {valid_signin} method michael hart'l has planned the event that capybara does not work and add some code to create a cookie directly in {valid_signin}, and if @falloutx add this part of code in his {valid_signin} it will be work, so the main question here is why the error become from this valid_signin method

Comment: @medBo, the page is temp down so I could see nothing. I don't think anything wrong in valid_signin and OP didn't mention it as well. You may fail at that because the user is already taken. I suggest you to open another question with your specific errors instead of discussing here as your error looks different from OP's. You are suggested to post related code in new question instead of referring some tuts to get a better answer.