# Can't understand no_capybara option in michael hart'l tutorial test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In rails tutorial by michael hart'l i can't understand a spec :

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do
  .
  .
  .
  describe "authorization" do
    .
    .
    .
    describe "as wrong user" do
     let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
     before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

     describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
        before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        it { should_not have_title(full_title('Edit user')) }
     end

     describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action" do
        before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
     end
   end
  end
end
```

as you see, the author use `before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }` to sign in user before each example. `no_capybara` option is declared as so :

spec/support/utilities.rb

```
.
. 
.
def sign_in(user, options={})
  if options[:no_capybara]
    # Sign in when not using Capybara.
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
  else
   visit signin_path
   fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
   fill_in "Password", with: user.password
   click_button "Sign in"
  end
end
```

as he noted in tutorial : This is necessary (he means no_capybara option) when using one of the HTTP request methods directly (get, post, patch, or delete), i can understand by this that in the **"submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action"** there is a  **patch** method in use, but what is the relationship between sign_in method above and this line (of patch method), in my understand i think that **sign_in** is used **before** using **patch** so why we should add this option of **no_capybara**

Answer (score 2):

My tests to the same section were failing with these messages:

```
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/signin>.
```

Is that the same for you? Isn't it strange for you that the URL is "http://www.example.com/"? We are not using this URL anywhere in our application. That's Capybara doing it. This means that, as all the others are saying, Capybara is not actually creating a cookie in our actual application, it's just doing a simulation of a sign-in. We would have to search more in the docs of Capybara to understand exactly how it works at this point. But you see that Capybara isn't doing an actual sign in. Now, if you see our `users_controller.rb`:

```
before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
```

Which in turn, do:

```
def signed_in_user
  redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
end

def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
end
```

So, when the test asks for:

```
before { get edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
```

it is automatically redirected to `signin_url` by the controller, since, as I said before, the user is not really signed-in, no cookie has been really set for him. That is why the cookie has to be set in advance.

Comment: Is there a solution to make the tests pass other than to comment out the tests that fail because of the lack of a cookie?

Comment: Yes, just use the sign_in method as defined in spec/support/utilities.rb, as posted in the question above. Notice that in `authentication_pages_spec.rb` we write: 
`describe "as wrong user" do
    [...]
    before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }`
This tells you that the `sign_in` method in `utilities.rb` uses the first part of the "if-else" to make the sign in. In this way, the tests pass because, as I said before, the cookie is being set properly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like he's just trying to make a faster / less dependent test suite.  When you go through the login process with the Capybara driver, the end result is that you get a cookie placed in the browser, which is what persists the user session between requests.

By providing a "no_capybara" option, you avoid having to render the signin page, find and fill in all the information, submit the page, and then redirect to the first page after login.  All you want in the cookie in the browser, so he's just setting that directly and skipping everything else.

Comment: he don't try to make faster/less as do you say, read the last paragraph in my question : This is necessary (he means no_capybara option) when using one of the HTTP request methods directly (get, post, patch, or delete)

Comment: You may be misunderstanding what he is saying, since your logic at the end of your question is correct. As you have shown it, the `no_capybara` option deals with skipping signin (which works just fine with capybara anyhow).  There is a patch request in your spec after signin, which Capybara cannot submit, but that doesn't have anything to do with your signin method as it is shown in your question.

Comment: but why when i use traditional way to sign in (without no_capybara option) it break my test and gives error ?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code, it's hard to say. It may be that once Capybara is initiated, it will perform the rest of the actions within the test.  By not initiating Capybara (with a GET request to sign in, for example), and by instead doing the PATCH request first, Capybara is not used as the driver.

Comment: this is possible ! but not sure ... this is what i want to know

Comment: Just try commenting out the `before_filter` that requires authentication in the controller, then comment out the login portion of the test suite.  If it works, then the tutorial is skipping the GET-based login for the reason I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

no_capybara is needed because capybara can't submit directly to 'patch' or 'put' HTTP methods.

See: [Why Capybara can't submit directly to put action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504669/why-capybara-cant-submit-directly-to-put-action)

Since capybara can't submit to put/patch, we need to make changes by hand, so thats why Micheal uses :no_capybara option to identify such situations.

Comment: i already read you question and response but what no_capybara does here is to create a cookie directly to connect the user, so what is the relation between connect user by cookie and put/patch ? also what do you means by submit to put/patch, you are confusing here, put and patch is a verb (in the Http standard) like post, it seem like you say submit a post/put/patch

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, and I couldn't understand either why you should use another kind of signin when using direct HTTP requests.

I've read again some parts of the Michael Hartl's tutorial and the reason seems to be that the cookies object doesn't work exactly the same way inside the tests, because it's only a simulation. So, for direct http requests, you can't just fill in the form and use the "regular" sign_in. You have to use the :no_capybara option to set the remember_token into the cookie directly.

I hope this comment of the author helps:

> As noted in the comment line, filling in the form doesn’t work when not using Capybara, so to cover this case we allow the user to pass the option no_capyabara: true to override the default signin method and manipulate the cookies directly. This is necessary when using one of the HTTP request methods directly (get, post, patch, or delete), as we’ll see in Listing 9.45. (Note that the test cookies object isn’t a perfect simulation of the real cookies object; in particular, the cookies.permanent method seen in Listing 8.19 doesn’t work inside tests.) As you might suspect, the sign_in method will prove useful in future tests, and in fact it can already be used to eliminate some duplication (Section 9.6).

Comment: hi @LuisRubio, i'm not agree with you about cookie, i think the key is here : "filling in the form doesn’t work when not using Capybara", which means that (get, post, patch, delete) are not from capybara and if you want to use them, you should simulate cookie directly :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late, but here is my understanding.
 If you use Capybara as a driver to sign in, he hold the remember_token in HIS cookie. However the next PATCH request will be submitted by the other person because Capybara does not have the ability to directly send that request to the web server. In this situation, the person who sent the request does not have the remember_token in the cookie which was used to sign in. This is why the test goes wrong.

This is not anything like initiating issue.