# Problems with testing page redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have been studying Ruby on Rails based on Micheal Hartl's tutorial book and encountered a very interesting problem with rspec testing of the redirection to the root page in case if some user in my website tries to edit profile of another one by hitting the appropriate url. The thing is that when I start the rails server and check this action manually, it actually redirects me to the root url, however, the spec tests show that:

```
Failure/Error: specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/signin>.
   Expected "http://www.example.com/" to be === "http://www.example.com/signin".
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:95:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have searched the net in order to find cure for this issue, and found that there are actually several similar problems and people advise to use `no_capybara: true` in the `rb` file, however, I have already used this solution. The code part for this test is below:

```
describe "as wrong user" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
  before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

  describe "submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action" do
    before { get edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
    specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user')) }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
  end

  describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action" do
    before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
  end
end
```

Controller code is also here:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user=User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    #Before filters

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
  end
```

Here are also session helper codes for the controller:

```
def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
end

def sign_out
    current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token))
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    self.current_user = nil
end

def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
end
```

I would be very glad for any answer, and ready to provide any details!

Comment: seems like the sign_in of the user is not working, would check this first if he really is signed in via debugger / byebug or just write a small test case to verify it with `get edit_user_path(user)`(should not redirect)

Comment: @jethroo Wow, I have done tests to see if user is really signed in in this example, and it appears that he is not. But I have the same tests (almost similar) also in by rb file, which tests the sign in page and authorization. I am a little of newbie here, have you any ideas why the problem exists?

Comment: can you check your `sign_in test` method, it should look like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620780/cant-understand-no-capybara-option-in-michael-hartl-tutorial-test, there is also an explanation why this option is needed

Comment: @jethroo Thank you very much! I finally found the solution and understood the problem. If you want, you can post your comment in the answer section, so I can accept it. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that the `sign_in` of the user is not working. Please check  first if the user really is signed in via debugger / byebug or just write a small test case to verify it with `get edit_user_path(user)` (it should not redirect).

You might also want to check if your test `sign_in` method is implemented correctly: [Can't understand no_capybara option in michael hart'l tutorial test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620780/cant-understand-no-capybara-option-in-michael-hartl-tutorial-test). The is also an explanation why `no_capybara` option has to be used here.